# Multiple Timers in C++ / MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, timer

I've got a service system that gets requests from another system. A request contains information that is stored on the service system's MySQL database. Once a request is received, the server should start a timer that will send a FAIL message to the sender if the time has elapsed.

The problem is, it is a dynamic system that can get multiple requests from the same, or various sources. If a request is received from a source with a timeout limit of 5 minutes, and another request comes from the same source after only 2 minutes, it should be able to handle both. Thus, a timer needs to be enabled for every incoming message. The service is a web-service that is programmed in C++ with the information being stored in a MySQL database.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Or perhaps you could put a time stamp on each incoming request and check which requests have timed out at regular intervals using just one timer?

Answer (score 1):

A way I've seen this often done: Use a SINGLE timer, and keep a priority queue (sorted by *target* time) of every timeout. In this way, you always know the amount of time you need to wait until the next timeout, and you don't have the overhead associated with managing hundreds of timers simultaneously.

Say at time 0 you get a request with a timeout of 100.

`Queue: [100]`

You set your timer to fire in 100 seconds.

Then at time 10 you get a *new* request with a timeout of 50.

`Queue: [60, 100]`

You cancel your timer and set it to fire in 50 seconds.

When it fires, it handles the timeout, removes `60` from the queue, sees that the next time is `100`, and sets the timer to fire in 40 seconds. Say you get *another* request with a timeout of 100, at time 80.

`Queue: [100, 180]`

In this case, since the head of the queue (`100`) doesn't change, you don't need to reset the timer. Hopefully this explanation makes the algorithm pretty clear.

Of course, each entry in the queue will need some link to the request associated with the timeout, but I imagine that should be simple.

Note however that this all may be unnecessary, depending on the mechanism you use for your timers. For example, if you're on Windows, you can use `CreateTimerQueue`, which I imagine uses this same (or very similar) logic internally.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I decided to timestamp incoming request and compare the current time to their timestamps to see whether they had timed out yet. So you do a check every main loop for every entry.